# Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables state(sehir), city(ilce) and neighbourhood(semtmah) and I added the following triggers so that when I delete a state, all the cities and neighbourhoods related to it should be deleted

```
Create trigger [dbo].[sehir_sil]
on [dbo].[Sehirler]
  instead of delete
  as 
begin
set nocount on
declare @id int

select @id = Sehirler.SehirId from Sehirler
delete from Ilceler where SehirId = @id
end
```

and

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[ilce_sil]
on [dbo].[Ilceler]
  instead of delete
  as 
begin
set nocount on
declare @id1 int

select @id1 = Ilceler.ilceId from Ilceler
delete from SemtMah where SemtMahId = (select top 1 SemtMahId  from semtmah where ilceId = @id1 order by SemtMahId)
end
```

and

```
Create trigger [dbo].[semtmah_sil]
on [dbo].[SemtMah]
  instead of delete
  as 
begin
set nocount on
declare @id2 int
declare @idsehir int

select @id2 = SemtMah.ilceId from SemtMah
select @idsehir = Ilceler.SehirId from Ilceler where ilceId = @id2
delete from SemtMah where ilceId in (select ilceId from Ilceler where SehirId = @idsehir)
delete from Ilceler where SehirId =@idsehir
delete from Sehirler where SehirId = @idsehir
end
```

when executing the query

```
delete from Sehirler where SehirId = 17
```

I got the error above at "Procedure ilce_sil, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]" although I tried to trigger the statement at line 10 (semtmah_sil) only once. My Recursive_triggers is already off
Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Your triggers have multiple MAJOR logical flaws. First is that you are using scalar values and assuming there will only ever be a single row deleted. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation. This leads to the second logical flaw. You are not referencing the deleted virtual table anywhere. The way you have coded this it will just delete whatever row from Ilceler it chooses and that problem will trickle down to the rest of your logic.

Comment: Why are you using a trigger for this?  It sounds like you'd be better served using a foreign key constraint that is set to cascade deletes.  Why would a trigger on the neighborhood issue a delete against the state?  That doesn't seem to make logical sense.  It's also causing an infinite loop...

Comment: I was trying to trigger a neighbourhood delete once in order for the query there to delete the rest, @SeanLange. But I neglected to mention what to delete. Let me try using cascade deletes instead, thanks

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave. I'm still new to sql server and didn't know about cascade deletes. That's why I came up with this flawed logic

Answer (score 0):

The logic was completely flawed but I achieved what I wanted using cascade deletes thanks to @JustinCave